# Fazer com que o Footer da modal Bootstrap exiba os botões alinhados verticalmente na parte inferior - Asp.net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, modal

Tenho uma janela modal que é genérica e é utilizada para fazer as operações de CRUD. Tenho um agrupamento de botões que precisam ser alinhados à esquerda e devem ficar sempre colados na parte inferior da modal, respeitando as bordas conforme imagem. No momento, eles ficam subindo e descendo conforme a quantidade de campos que janela possui... Gostaria que o footer e eles se mantessem fixos na parte inferior.

Obrigado a todos!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.modal-content {
    height: 90%; 
}

.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 70%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto !important; 
}

#contentModal {
    overflow: auto; 
}

#modalGenerica {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-body {
  
}

.modal-content {
    /*background-color: #f8f7fc;*/
}

.modal-footer {
  
}

.modal-header {
    background-color: #ecece9;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form asp-action="Create" id="frmCreate">
    <div class="modal-shadow">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center"> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
      </div>

      @await Html.PartialAsync("_PessoaFisicaJuridica") @*

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <button id="btnSalvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Salvar </button>
          <button id="btnFechar" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon wb-close"></i> Fechar </button>
        </div>
      </div>*@

      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="float-left">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
              <a asp-action="Create" data-modal="" class="btn btn-success text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Nova Pessoa" data-container="body">
                <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs">Nova Pessoa</span>
              </a>
              <a id="btnPesquisaAvancada" class="btn btn-dark text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" data-container="body">
                <i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span class="hidden-xs">Pesquisa Avançada</span>
              </a>
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <a data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" class="btn  btn-dark text-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="icon wb-grid-4" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mais Ações
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleGroupDrop2" role="menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>Importar</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Exportar</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>Imprimir</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```html
//Modal
<div class="modal fade" id="modalGenerica" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="contentModal">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o Bootstrap  4 use a classe `mr-auto`.

---

**Exemplo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm mr-auto" role="group">
          <a asp-action="Create" data-modal="" class="btn btn-success text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Nova Pessoa" data-container="body">
            <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="hidden-xs">Nova Pessoa</span>
          </a>
          <a id="btnPesquisaAvancada" class="btn btn-dark text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" data-container="body">
            <i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="hidden-xs">Pesquisa Avançada</span>
          </a>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
            <a data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" class="btn  btn-dark text-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="icon wb-grid-4" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mais Ações
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleGroupDrop2" role="menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>Importar</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Exportar</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>Imprimir</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Para o Bootstrap  3 use a classe `pull-left`.

---

**Exemplo**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Netinho Santos, mas não funcionou. Os botões nem se moveram.

Comment: @JalberRomano remova todos os estilos do modal que você criou e crie um modal cru seguindo um desses exemplos e veja se dá certo. Certamente um desses estilos que você postou deve está matando a classe do bootstrap. Att.

Comment: descobri o problema: No meu css o bloco .modal-content {
    height: 90%; /*altura da modal*/ está atrapalhando. Eu comentei e funcionou... Mas não existe uma maneira de conciliá-los não? preciso muito informar a altura da janela...
}

Comment: .modal-footer {
      justify-content: flex-start; 
    }
Tenta isso

Comment: Nãoo funcionou.... o Ruim é que se eu descomentar .modal-content { height: 90%;} o mr-auto não funciona...